# Subversion directory in Documents has corrupted file structure

Tags: windows, svn

When my tortoise svn folder of my project is in my Documents folder it shows lots of strange svn type files, and no directory structure, just everything in one messy folder. However when I cut and paste the directory out of Documents to say c:\, I see the files and folders just fine, without all the subversion strange files?!? I have windows 7 Pro, 64 bit. I wanted to give an image of the strange files but need a rep of 10....

Comment: Which version of TortoiseSVN are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In the upper-right corner of the Document directory in question, make sure that **Arrange by:** is set to **Folder** rather than **Name**.

Alternatively, press **Alt** to open the menu bar, and select **View -> Arrange by -> Folder**

The **Name** view is consolidating everything into a flat structure, and displaying non-hidden files that are contained within the hidden .svn directories.